# SwiftUI, apply drawGesture only when over Image

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, uiimage

I'm try to apply the gesture only when the user is over the Image display not when tapped outside the image.

Any suggestion how I can do? this following code draw also when user tap outside the image.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var am = AppManager()
    @State var switchToTakePicture = false
    @State var paths: [PathContainer] = []
    @State var currentDraggingId = UUID()
    @State var spikoPic = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "spiko-16.jpeg")
    @State var centerOFimage = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Image(uiImage: spikoPic)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .position(x: proxy.size.width/2, y: proxy.size.height/2)
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                        Color.clear.preference(key: ViewRectKey.self,
                                               value: [$0.frame(in: .global)])
                    })
                    .gesture(drawGesture) // not correct
                
                ForEach(paths) { container in
                    // draw and set the foreground color of the paths to red
                    container.path
                        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 4)
                    
                    
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewRectKey.self) { rects in
                print(rects.first ?? .zero)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    var drawGesture: some Gesture {
        
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { value in
                
                // The point that the gesture started from
                let start = value.startLocation
                // The point that the gesture ended to
                let end = value.location
                // the properties of the rectangle to be drawn
                let rectangle: CGRect = .init(origin: end,
                                              size: .init(width: start.x - end.x,
                                                          height: start.y - end.y))
                // create a path for the rectangle
                let path: Path = .init { path in
                    
                    path.addRect(rectangle)
                }
                
                print("rettangolo = \(rectangle) orig \(rectangle.origin) - height \(rectangle.height) width = \(rectangle.width)")
                
                // remove the previous rectangle that was drawen in current
                // process of drawing
                paths.removeAll { $0.id == currentDraggingId }
                // append the new rectangle
                paths.append(.init(id: currentDraggingId, path: path))
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                // renew the dragging id so the app know that the next
                // drag gesture is drawing a completely new rectangle,
                // and is not continuing the drawing of the last rectangle
                currentDraggingId = .init()
            }
    }
}
```

i want no box outside

[image]

Comment: Drag itself is not limited to a view in which it is started, it just defines a coordinates context and handler. You need manually to limit where/how do you want to limit dragging. Next solves similar task so should be helpful.

Comment: Try to have your image in a geometry read to get its size and then use it in the drawGesture to limit drag.

Comment: I solved by using this example..https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-the-location-of-a-tap-inside-a-view